# Garmin Connect Xamarin/C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, garmin

Is it possible to connect to toybox garmin module in c#/xamarin?

https://github.com/333fred/garmin-connect-sdk-xamarin
I already tried to implement this and have been able to connect. After connect using that code I want to read gps lattitute and longitute.

Until now i haven’t found a way to import the toybox module in c#.

Comment: Do you tried to install it as nuget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/GarminConnectSDK.Android

Comment: Crazy that they have there own homebrewn language …

Comment: yes, they have their own environtment, own language, own "app store".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now im understand , the toybox module is not in the nuget package or in c# environtment, its in monkey c, we have to create apps in monkey c , install to garmin device, and then our xamarin will retrieve the data